# Passing Query string using Jquery Post method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I want to use query string in my URL using Jquery ajax  below are my codes :

```
function load_content()
    {
        var msg=$(".message_box:last").attr("id");
        var baseurl = $("#baseurl").val();
        var ids = msg.split('-');
        var url = baseurl+"shops/load_allshops/"+{/literal}{php} if($_GET['country']!=''){ echo "?country=".$_GET['country']."&state=".$_GET['country']."&city=".$_GET['city']."&area=".$_GET['area'];}{/php}{literal};

        $.post(url, {start: ids[0], limit: ids[1]},
        function(data){
            if (data != "") {
                $(".message_box:last").after(data);
            }
            $('.last_msg_loader').fadeOut();
            });
        };
```

Error :

```
 SyntaxError: syntax error


...url = baseurl+"shops/load_allshops/"+?country=India&state=India&city=Madurai&are...
```

pointing near +?country

Please let me know the error

Comment: ?country=India&state=India&city=Madurai&are...  this part should be a string.

Comment: `"shops/load_allshops/"+?country` must be `"shops/load_allshops/"+"?country`. Check strings concated to the baseurl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, a POST request can include query string as well, however normally it doesn't.

A standard HTML form with a POST action will not include query string, therefore either you need to change your action type to GET or send data through hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

your url must be like this...

```
  ...url = baseurl+"shops/load_allshops/?country="+ India + "&state="+India+"&city="+ Madurai+"&are..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with arrays:

```
function load_content(){
//Your vars
var data=new Array();

//Just do some vars to get their value...
data[0]=$('#country').val();
data[1]=$('#city').val();
data[2]=$('#area').val();

//Forget to split or vars for url...

var data={"data":data};
$.post('getdata.php',data,function(data){
//And show php answer here...
alert(data);
});
return false;

}
```

---

example of getdata.php

```
<?php
$data=$_POST['data'];
echo "Country: $data[0]";
echo "City: $data[1]";
echo "Area: $data[2]";
?>
```

---

Arrays are useful. Have fun!